# Out of Memory Exception Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am developing a windows phone 8.1 app that takes a photo, stores it, puts it into a writeablebitmap so that I can rotate it in order to display the result accurately. Happens to be that I need to use two writeablebitmaps to do that.
I also convert the image to bytes so that I can send it over a service if necessary.

The following steps generate an exception:

I take a photo, say it's ok, it displays the photo for me.
Next I try to take another photo, because I was not satisfied with the previous result, and I get an out of memory exception on the

newWriteableBitmap = writeableBitmap.Rotate(90);

I write to the same variables, same viewmodel, same everything. It seems like there seems to be some kind of memory leak somewhere? I would REALLY like to avoid GC.collect and related. I accept any kind of improvements and suggestions, I do believe the code can be refactored to something way better.

Thanks,

```
private async Task TakePhoto()
        {
            _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Auto = false;
            _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Enabled = ((CameraViewModel) this.DataContext).FlashEnable;
            if (_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Supported)
            {
                await _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
            }

            if (_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Supported)
            {
                _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Enabled = true;
            }
            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            ImageEncodingProperties imageEncodingProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
            StorageFile cardStorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("cardStorageFile" + guid.ToString() + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imageEncodingProperties, cardStorageFile);


            ((CameraViewModel)this.DataContext).CardBitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(cardStorageFile.Path));
            await ((CameraViewModel)this.DataContext).CardBitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(await cardStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));

            WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(((CameraViewModel)this.DataContext).CardBitmapImage.PixelWidth, ((CameraViewModel)this.DataContext).CardBitmapImage.PixelHeight);
            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await cardStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                await writeableBitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            }
            WriteableBitmap newWriteableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(((CameraViewModel)this.DataContext).CardBitmapImage.PixelHeight, ((CameraViewModel)this.DataContext).CardBitmapImage.PixelWidth);
            newWriteableBitmap = writeableBitmap.Rotate(90);

            PhotoPreviewImage.Source = newWriteableBitmap;

            await ImageTobyte(cardStorageFile, value => ((CameraViewModel)this.DataContext).CardByte = value);
            ((CameraViewModel)this.DataContext).CaptureEnable = false;
            ((CameraViewModel)this.DataContext).IsBusy = false;
        }



        public async Task<byte[]> ImageTobyte(StorageFile myImageFile, Action<byte[]> setResultAction)
        {
            using (Stream ms = await myImageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
            {
                byte[] imageBytes = new byte[(int) ms.Length];
                ms.Read(imageBytes, 0, (int) ms.Length);
                setResultAction(imageBytes);
                return imageBytes;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution by making a major refactoring as is shown below. I believe there are still some improvements that can be made.

```
private async Task TakePhoto()
        {
            _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Auto = false;
            _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Enabled = ((CameraViewModel) this.DataContext).FlashEnable;
            if (_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Supported)
            {
                await _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
            }

            if (_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Supported)
            {
                _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Enabled = true;
            }

            ImageEncodingProperties imageEncodingProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            StorageFile cardStorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("cardStorageFile" + guid.ToString() + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            using (var imageStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imageEncodingProperties, imageStream);

                BitmapDecoder dec = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
                BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(imageStream, dec);

                enc.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;

                await enc.FlushAsync();


                using (var fileStream = await cardStorageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(imageStream, fileStream.AsOutputStream());
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }

            using (var randomAccessStream = await cardStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                if (((CameraViewModel) this.DataContext).CardBitmapImage == null)
                {
                    VideoEncodingProperties photoSizeEncodingProperties = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo) as VideoEncodingProperties;

                    if (photoSizeEncodingProperties != null)
                    {
                        ((CameraViewModel) this.DataContext).CardBitmapImage = new WriteableBitmap((int) photoSizeEncodingProperties.Width, (int) photoSizeEncodingProperties.Height);
                    }
                }
                await ((CameraViewModel)this.DataContext).CardBitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(randomAccessStream);
            }

            ((CameraViewModel) this.DataContext).StorageFileImage = cardStorageFile;

            ((CameraViewModel)this.DataContext).CaptureEnable = false;
            ((CameraViewModel)this.DataContext).IsBusy = false;
        }
```